# Access private facebook group's posts using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying (with little success) for a while now to get all the posts from a private group that I am in and display them on our website so that the people with
out Facebook can still see them. I know this is possible with a public group (which our group cannot be), but is it possible with a private group?

I've tried access tokens on the Graph API Explorer, but that just returns:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I also read that to access private groups the user needs to log in as a user in that group. However, this would be pointless as the whole point in trying to do this is to allow people without facebook to see the group's posts.

Thank you all

Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of a "private" group is that only logged in group members can see the feed.

That being said, you can only use the permission `user_managed_groups` to get the group feed with the `/group-id/feed` endpoint. You need to use a User Access Token for this, with the correct permission, and this only works as group admin. You can't read the feed of a group just because the user is a member of the group - at least not anymore.

Comment: Okay thank you - I thought this might be the case but wanted to check

Comment: It was possible until Graph API v2.3, requesting the "user_groups" permission that is no longer available.